# How to update supported languages in i18n after login?

Tags: internationalization, react-i18next

I am building an ERP application. We want to let user add their own translation files. At the beginning before this future, my i18n.js file was like this

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

    i18n
        .use(Backend)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({
            supportedLngs: ['en', 'tr', 'de'],
            debug: false,
            fallbackLng: "de",
            backend: {
                loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json",
            },
            react: {
                useSuspense: false,
            },
            detection:{
                order: ['localStorage', 'htmlTag', 'cookie', 'querystring', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'path', 'subdomain'],
            }
        });
    
    export default i18n;
```

and then I change it after adding this future, the main idea is if they create their own translation file I want to reload i18n

```
import i18n from "i18next";
    import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";
    import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
    import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
    
    let languageSettings = {
        supportedLngs: ['en', 'tr'],
        loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
    };
    
    const updateLanguageSettings = (supportedLngs, loadPath) => {
        languageSettings.supportedLngs = supportedLngs;
        languageSettings.loadPath = loadPath;
        // Dil ayarlarını güncelledikten sonra i18n konfigürasyonunu yeniden başlat
        i18n.reloadResources().then(r => {
            console.log("Dil ayarları güncellendi");
        });
    };
    
    i18n
        .use(Backend)
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({
            supportedLngs: languageSettings.supportedLngs,
            debug: true,
            fallbackLng: "tr",
            backend: {
                loadPath: languageSettings.loadPath,
            },
            react: {
                useSuspense: true,
            },
            detection: {
                order: ['localStorage', 'htmlTag', 'cookie', 'querystring', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'path', 'subdomain'],
            },
            lng: "tr",
        });
    
    export { i18n, updateLanguageSettings };
```

now when I refresh the page it load fallback language. The main idea is I want to let user change json translation files.

I want to let user create their own i18n translation files, if they create them I want to reload i18n. But when I reload i18n it loads fallback language. And translation doesn't work anymore.